# Cannot access Refs methods from parent component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I have a class component that I use in another parent component. I'm trying to call a method in the child component from the parent component. I'm getting a typeerror saying that the method I am calling is not a function.

Here's the simplified version of my code.

Child Component -

```
<template>
 // HTML Template
</template>

<script>
 import { Vue, Component, Ref } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

 @Component
 export default class ChildComponent extends Vue {

   doSomething(){
     //do something here 
   }

 }

</script>
```

Parent Component -

```
<template>
 // HTML template
  
  <child-component refs="child" />

</template>

<script>
 import { Vue, Component, Ref } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
 import ChildComponent from '/....'

 @Component({
   components: { ChildComponent }
 })
 export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {

   @Ref("child") readonly child!: ChildComponent;

   doAnotherThing(){
     //do something here
       this.child.doSomething() //this will return typerror that says it;s not a function
   }

 }

</script>
```

Comment: `@Ref` is simply a decorator, it doesn't change the underlying Vue functionality. You'll still need to type `this.$refs.child.doSomething()`

Comment: I've tried doing it like that. It still wont work